# MySQLi API and how transactions work & commit

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, transactions

With regards to using PHP's [API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.transactions.php) for MySQL transaction support I was wondering about `autocommit`.

For example, I'm not sure how it works by default, but ideally I would like all queries to auto commit *unless* I explicitly start a transaction with something like:

```
$db->begin_transaction();
$db->query(...);
$db->query(...);
$db->commit();
```

As a related question, I notice `begin_transaction()` wasn't introduced until *PHP 5.5* so is it possible to get behaviour before 5.5?

I know there is `$db->autocommit()` but does that mean if I want the above behaviour I would need to have it on by default and then do `$db->autocommit(false)` before any transactions and then `$db->autocommit(true)` afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html) on transactions and the `autocommit` setting.

To quote from that documentation:

> By default, MySQL runs with autocommit mode enabled. This means that as soon as you execute a statement that updates (modifies) a table, MySQL stores the update on disk to make it permanent. The change cannot be rolled back.

As I read this, the way it works is this:

Imagine you're making queries without using transactions. You do an `INSERT` with autocommit **on** and that INSERT happens immediately (ie. is stored to disk right away). An `UPDATE`? It happens immediately.

Now imagine you turn off `autocommit` and make queries the same way. The quote above implies that if you perform that `INSERT` command with `autocommit` off, it is not immediately stored to disk. So what happens to that `INSERT`? To quote from the documentation again:

> After disabling autocommit mode by setting the autocommit variable to zero, changes to transaction-safe tables (such as those for InnoDB or NDBCLUSTER) are not made permanent immediately. You must use COMMIT to store your changes to disk or ROLLBACK to ignore the changes.

So, in short, using `autocommit` is a different way of implementing transactions. In MySQL you can do this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 2, 3);
COMMIT;
```

or you can do this:

```
SET autocommit=0;
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 2, 3);
COMMIT;
```

Note too that there's an implicit commit when you change the `autocommit` value - so doing this would be equivalent:

```
SET autocommit=0;
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 2, 3);
SET autocommit=1;
```

You can do things the same way in PHP, using either `$db->begin_transaction();` or `$db->autocommit(false);` to start the transaction, the doing `$db->commit();` at the end. Personally, I find the `begin_transaction` method clearer.

Comment: So what you're saying is `autocommit` controls *all* queries and if I want queries not prepended by a `begin_transaction` to autocommit then I will need to set `autocommit(true)` by default and then `autocommit(false)` before a transaction and then `autocommit(true)` after the transaction? If so, then what is even the purpose of the `begin_transaction`?

Comment: The way I read the MySQL docs, `BEGIN TRANSACTION` is a synonym for `SET autocommit=0` at the level of the MySQL server and are interchangeable. `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` offer additional options for greater control over transactions. Are the PHP `begin_transaction` and `autocommit(false)` methods interchangeable? They should be, if PHP is simply wrapping the MySQL statements.

Comment: What is the purpsoe of `begin_transaction`? Well, presumably, it ought to offer some of the addtional options that MySQL has for `BEGIN TRANSACTION` but the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) is pretty sparse - there's a warning that says 'This function is currently not documented; only its argument list is available.' :-/

Comment: Ok, so from what you have said the situation I would like I would need to make sure `autocommit(true)` is on by default and then as long as I used `BEGIN TRANSACTION` or `SET autocommit=0` to start the transaction I would be good; then afterwards I would have to do `SET autocommit=1` to turn it back on? If so, I'd probably just make a class to wrap this functionality.

Comment: Autocommit is on by default; you could use `BEGIN TRANSACTION`/`COMMIT` or `SET autocommit=0`/`SET autocommit=1` to enclose transactions; I'd probably use the former because it seems clearer to me.

Comment: True, but running a `COMMIT` by itself is not going to reset `autocommit` back to `1` and hence I would still need to run `autocommit=1` no!?